# DbUtils Query runner usage of batch performance

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, apache-commons-dbutils

We have an application which selects rows from database based on a status, processes it and updates the status, so that it is not picked up again.
We have been using Apache DBUtils Query Runner to execute the queries and to caste the items to a bean using a bean handler.

We have been using queryRunner.update(Connection, updateQuery) by giving a query which updates based on 'ID's using 'IN' clause.

```
UPDATE TABLE SET STATUS = 'P' WHERE ID IN ('id1', 'id2'....);
```

But we realized that Oracle has a limitation of 1000 items to keep in the 'IN' clause but we wanted to try selecting more records and update them. This is because as the fetch count increased, we noticed better performance.

So we thought of using,

```
public int[] batch(Connection conn,
                   String sql,
                   Object[][] params)
            throws SQLException;
```

and pass the 'ID's in the params.

I would like to know the below,

1. In a plain select and update, which one will perform better,
   a. Low fetch count and update using IN with lesser items. (higher number of loops).
   b. Higher fetch count and update using IN with higher items. (lower number of loops).
2. Does `QueryRunner.batch` have the limitation of 1000 items in 'IN' statement or does it use a different mechanism?
3. Does `QueryRunner.batch` actually update one by one and end up performing worse than using 'IN' clause?

Kindly help me here. Apologies for multiple questions.

Comment: The use of IN with 1000 parameters to do batching like this causes a lot of problems. The parse time is excessive, the memory requirements for each cursor is extremely high, parsing concurrency latches and mutexes are held longer causing issues for other sessions, and the lack of bind variables means a new cursor is needed every time. It's not scalable. We shut down any user using this methodology for this reason. The appropriate way is to loop one row at a time. If you need batch processing, array insert the IDs into a temp table and use that to drive a one-time update or merge on the status.

Comment: You can also build a client array and bind it to a procedure parameter input, which then in PL/SQL loops through the array and processes each update singly. This will perform quite well because you've taken the network out of the loop.

Comment: The traditional solution is to create a [private temporary table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/admin/managing-tables.html#GUID-9B373086-0760-4B18-9688-BACFF07EC74B), store all the IDs in it, and then just join it with the main query. This way the query won't be limited to 1000 elements, and can have much more values than that.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. That was helpful. What would be DBUtils.QueryRunner.batch would be doing? Will it create a temporary table internally? How is its mechanism of action? Also, it is mentioned looping will help but doesnt looping a performance hit, as it has to send the single query across network all the time?